# If value >= 15 statement TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I work at the moment with the ZapWorks program. The code is write in TypeScript. With this program I try to make a game. Now I have the following problem. I have created a score:

```
var score = 0;
```

When an object is pressed:

```
score++;
```

Now I want if the score is 16 (which is printed on all objects) you get the message that you have found them all. This is now my if statement:

```
if (score >= 15)
{
 CharcuterieSansInline_ttf1.visible(true);
 CharcuterieSansInline_ttf1.text("Je hebt alle dieren!");
 console.log(score.toString());
}
```

Only If statement is not working. The score works, because in the console I can see increment of score, and the text changed too, but not in the if. What goes wrong?

Comment: When are you executing the if statement?

Comment: if `if statement` not working then how it is printing data in console,coz the line to write the data in console is written inside the if?

Comment: I've add the code on an object. When i press on the object, the data showed in the console. But when i use the if statement the code won't work. @Paarth At the end of the code, under the latest pointerdown object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know why its is not working in your code .. i just try following code in my pc its works fine.

```
<html>
<script>
var a = 0;
a++
if(a>=0)
{
    alert("sdsd");
}
</script>
</html>
```

as u mention you use typeScript so you need to define type of var like

```
var score:number = 0 ;
```

and after you can `score++` and then condition check

Comment: try this var score:number  = 0 and the if..else

Comment: if it is working now then please vote my ans :) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

It works! The problem: on all the pointerdowns i have to place the if statement. Thanks everybody!